# How to implement Facebook AccountKit based login system with custom django User Model

Tags: django, facebook, django-rest-framework, django-users, account-kit

Facebook introduced [AccountKit](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/accountkit) that helps you quickly register for apps using just your phone number or email address — no password needed. It's reliable, easy to use and gives you a choice about how you sign up for apps.

I have read the [docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/accountkit) but have no idea how to integrate the AccountKit user with custom django user model. And how session will be maintained.

If someone explain the flow, It would be great help ? 
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Please check this repositiry https://github.com/antiproblemist/django-accountkit for Accountkit integration with Django (will be updating the documentation soon). You can `pip install django-accountkit` to use this package